# How to download HAXM for Windows on AS

Tags: android

I recently got Android Studio, but whenever I try running it, it says I need to have HAXM. I have tried doing all the methods to do so on the Intel website, such as downloading on the SDK manager on AS, but it just said "fail to update status" I believe but I might be wrong, something along those lines, and downloading extracting files from Intel HAXM website, turning on certain items on the control panel for the laptop, but it still doesn't work.

I tried turning on settings in the control panel corresponding to the tutorials, I tried downloading HAXM from the AS SDK manager, and downloading & extracting files from the Intel website following the instructions and doing all the methods, all failed.

Comment: HAXM is deprecated by Intel is no longer needed and and should no be used anymore. Just make sure virtualization features are enabled in UEFI BIOS and Hyper-V is enabled in your Windows system.